# Laravel basic view returning route does not work

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.4

I have this problem when I try to access the page vie link it works properly. But when I try to write the route inside a link in order to access it using navbar, it throws the following Error :

> Route [home] not defined. (View: C:\wamp64\www\projectName\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp64\www\projectName\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php)

And my route is as following:

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
return view('home');
});
```

This is how I write the route inside the navbar link:

```
{{ Route('home') }}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use named route you have to give `name` to that particular route. change your code to:

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
return view('home');
})->name('home);
```